set cookies while building suggestions in solr
I am new to solr. In our project solr we deployed in azure web app. Azure web app having 3 instances. The problem I am facing to load the suggestions in all 3 instances. How to set the cookie while making solr request?
I am using HttpSolrclient where withcookiestore, we can make request -
HttpCookie Cookie=new HttpCookie("ARRAffinity","instanceid");
        URI uri=URI.create("http://--solrurl--/solr");
        String solrUrl="--solrurl--/solr";
        cookieStore.add(uri,Cookie);
        http2solrClient = new Http2SolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).withCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
        return http2solrClient;

Its failing with error - IOException occurred when talking to server. frame_size_Error/invalid_frame_length

Please add more details about the issue.

@Harshitha Updated in the ticket
